# windows cli cmd.exe /c not working with http link as a parameter

Tags: windows, command-line

if I run the following command

```
cmd.exe /c "D:\test\phantomjs.exe -h >D:\test\test.txt"
```

I get nice output in test.txt for the help of the exe. Yet if I execute the following command:

```
cmd.exe /c "D:\test\phantomjs.exe save_page.js http://mytest.com/testapp/test.html >D:\test\test.txt"
```

I get a text.text with no output. it seems like the cmd.exe using /c is not working with the HTTP parameter I have...

So, if I just straight click start/run and open a new command window, cd to my d:\test and execute the command as :

```
phantomjs.exe save_page.js http://mytest.com/testapp/test.html >D:\test\test.txt
```

it works absolutely fine :) lol.. I am not understanding why the same will not work when calling cmd.exe with /c ?? on a longer note I am trying to start this process in C# but in my troubleshooting I found that my root cause I think is the fact that it will not even work manually outside of C# thus here I am stuck trying to fig out why this will not work with "cmd/exe /c" . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found if if used /k instead of /c it would leave the cmd window open :) then I was able to see that it could not find save_page.js and that I was sitting in c:\windows\system32 due to the cmd /c or /k ugh lol.. so using this set of parameters worked

```
cmd.exe /c ""D:\test\phantomjs.exe" "D:\test\save_page.js" http://mytest.com/testapp/test.html >D:\test\test.txt"
```

note to anyone tshooting cmd.exe /c , don't forget about /k it leaves the cmd windows that is created open so you can see what is going on ;)